# How define his own server with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want use always thin when I start my rails server in development mode.

By default it webrick to use. So I add thin in my Gemfile

```
gem 'thin', :group => 'development'
```

Now If I want use it to launch my server in development mode I mandatory define it.

```
bundle exec rails s thin
```

If I don't define it, it's always use webrick. So How define using thin by default ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `rails s` just type :

```
>> thin start -p 3000
```

Where 3000 is the number of your port.

You can also specify an enviornment :

```
>> thin start -e production
```

Comment: It seems like it should, though I have little experience with it. Here's some infos http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-techniques-revealed-autoload-1652.html  and http://www.softiesonrails.com/2008/4/27/using-thin-instead-of-mongrel

Comment: Autoloading should work with this. Its also interesting to note that mongrel becomes default if we include it in the gemfile, but its not the case with thin. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I think it's historical. Because this behaviour is present since a long time ago.

Comment: Just a note: if I use `bundle exec thin start`, there is no request logging to stdout. On the other hand, if I use `bundle exec rails server thin` request logging works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bundler 1.0.x and your gems is vendorized:

`bundle exec vendor/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin start`